# Converting min:sec to a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert something in a format such as min:sec to a number?

This is what I have at the moment, but I know there is a cleaner way of doing this. This is for a game which is only 30 minutes in length, so at worst I have 30 switch statements, but it's just far too ugly to stare at each day.

```
// 1:15
var minSecToNum = function minSecToNum(minutes, seconds) {
    var min = minutes || 0;
    var sec = seconds || 0;

    switch (min) {
    case 1:
        sec += 60;
        break;
    case 2:
        sec += 120;
        break;
    case 3:
        sec += 180;
        break;
    case 4:
        sec += 240;
        break;
    case 5:
        sec += 300;
        break;
    }
    return sec;
};

console.log(minSecToNum(1, 15)); // Returns 75
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function minSecToNum(minutes, seconds) {
    var min = minutes || 0;
    var sec = seconds || 0;

    return minutes*60 + seconds;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a hero for the people. Thank you. SO says I can mark this as correct in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Whatever your input for minutes (1,2, 15, etc.), just multiply that by 60, then add the total seconds to that.

so your function looks like this:

```
function minSecToNum(m, s) {
  return ((60*m)+s)); 
}
```

That avoids the need for all of the switch statements.

So given your input of 1 minute, 15 seconds,

the new function would output (60*1)+15 = 75

For 3 minutes 45 seconds, you would get (60*3)+45 = 225